# How to Calculate Available Internal Storage Memory In MB?

Tags: android

I want to calculate available Internal Storage Memory in MB ?

How can i get the value of that ?

Please Help me........

Answer (score 8, accepted):

hi chirag using the following function you can calculate available Internal Storage Memory in MB.

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
    long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getFreeBlocks() * (long)stat.getBlockSize();;
    long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / 1048576;
```

enjoy...........

Comment: Is it return the value in MB ?

Comment: yes it can calculate available Internal Storage Memory in bytes and then converting into Mb